# Zooming image in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing

I have a problem in zooming an image. I have successfully zoomed the image but the image breaks when it is scrolled up or down.

```
public partial class ImageDetail : UserControl
{
    public delegate void onClose();
    public event onClose close;
    Image pbImage;
    public ImageDetail(Image img)
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox.Image = img;
        pbImage = img;
        pictureBox.Width = this.pbImage.Width;
        pictureBox.Height = this.pbImage.Height;
        panel2.AutoScroll = true;
        panel2.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = img.Width;
        panel2.VerticalScroll.Maximum   = img.Height;
        panel2.HorizontalScroll.Minimum = 0;
        panel2.VerticalScroll.Minimum   = 0;
        panel2.SetAutoScrollMargin(10, 10);            
    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (close != null)
            close(); 
    }        

    private void DrawImage(int startX, int startY)
    {            
        if (this.pbImage == null) { return; }

        Graphics pbGraphics = this.pictureBox.CreateGraphics();
        BufferedGraphicsContext currentGraphicsContext = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
        Rectangle targetRect = new Rectangle(startX, startY, (this.pbImage.Width + tmpWidth), (this.pbImage.Height + tmpHeight));
        using (BufferedGraphics pbGDIBuffer = currentGraphicsContext.Allocate(pbGraphics, targetRect))
        {
            Rectangle drawRect = new Rectangle(startX, startY, (this.pbImage.Width + tmpWidth), (this.pbImage.Height + tmpHeight));

            pbGDIBuffer.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(this.pbImage, drawRect);
            pbGDIBuffer.Render();                
        }
        pictureBox.Width = this.pbImage.Width + tmpWidth;
        pictureBox.Height = this.pbImage.Height + tmpHeight;
    }             

    int tmpWidth = 0, tmpHeight = 0;
    private void toolStripSplitButton1_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmpWidth = tmpWidth + ((this.pbImage.Width * 20) / 100);
        tmpHeight = tmpHeight + ((this.pbImage.Height * 20) / 100);

        pictureBox.Width = this.pbImage.Width + tmpWidth;
        pictureBox.Height = this.pbImage.Height + tmpHeight;
        pictureBox.Refresh();
        DrawImage(0, 0);
    }

    private void toolStripSplitButton2_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(tmpWidth > 0)
            tmpWidth = tmpWidth - ((this.pbImage.Width * 20) / 100);
        if(tmpHeight > 0)
            tmpHeight = tmpHeight - ((this.pbImage.Height * 20) / 100);
        if (tmpHeight < 0)
            tmpHeight = 0;
        if (tmpWidth < 0)
            tmpWidth = 0;
        pictureBox.Refresh();
        DrawImage(0, 0);                      
    }

    private void panel2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox.Width = this.pbImage.Width + tmpWidth;
        pictureBox.Height = this.pbImage.Height + tmpHeight;
    }

    private void panel2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox.Width = this.pbImage.Width + tmpWidth;
        pictureBox.Height = this.pbImage.Height + tmpHeight;
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens to the image when you try to scroll? Does it not display properly?

Comment: image into two sections each override, the image at the top is the result of zooming and the bottom image is the image with an initial size. when at the top of the picture scroll slowly erased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to draw image on [`Paint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) event (eg):

```
pictureBox.Paint += (sender, e) =>
    {
        var drawRect = new Rectangle(startX, startY, pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(this.pbImage, drawRect);
    };
```

and after resizing call [`Invalidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.invalidate.aspx) method:

```
pictureBox.Invalidate();
```

---

and your code should be like this:

```
public ImageDetail(Image img)
{
    pictureBox.Image = img;
    pbImage = img;
    ...
    pictureBox.Paint += pictureBox_Paint;
}

void pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (pbImage == null) { return; }
    var drawRect = new Rectangle(startX, startY, pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);
    e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(this.pbImage, drawRect);
}

private void toolStripSplitButton1_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ///... resize to what you need 
    pictureBox.Width = (int) (pbImage.Width*0.2);
    pictureBox.Height = (int) (pbImage.Height * 0.2);
    pictureBox.Invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Zoom an image without using picture box. Here is the zoom code that will zoom the image drawn using Graphcs.DrawImage method in c#. Hope you Will understand.[check ImageZoom.cs](https://github.com/devkotaDmanohar/ZoomImage)

or here is the code.

```
   public static  class ImageZoom
{
 /// <summary>
 /// returns the zoomed rectangle to zoom an image
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="imageRectangle">display rectangle of given image</param>
 /// <param name="mousepoint">current position of mouse</param>
 /// <param name="zoomFactor">positive value to zoom in and negetive value to zoom out </param>
 /// <returns></returns>
    public static RectangleF Zoom(RectangleF imageRectangle, Point mousepoint, float zoomFactor)
    {
        //orginal size and location of image
        SizeF OrginalSize = imageRectangle.Size;
        PointF Orginalpoint = imageRectangle.Location;
        //Mouse cursor location -located in width% and height% of totaloriginal image
        float mouse_widthPercent = System.Math.Abs(Orginalpoint.X - mousepoint.X) / OrginalSize.Width * 100;
        float mouse_heightPercent = System.Math.Abs(Orginalpoint.Y - mousepoint.Y) / OrginalSize.Height * 100;


        //Zoomed Image by scalefactor
        SizeF newSize = new SizeF(
             OrginalSize.Width + OrginalSize.Width * zoomFactor,
             OrginalSize.Height + OrginalSize.Height * zoomFactor
             );

        if (newSize.Width > 50000 || newSize.Height > 50000 || newSize.Width < 10 || newSize.Height < 10)
            return imageRectangle;

        //How much width increases and height increases
        float width_incrasesBy = newSize.Width - OrginalSize.Width;
        float height_incresesBy = newSize.Height - OrginalSize.Height;

        //Adjusting Image location after zooming the image
        PointF newPoint = new PointF(

              Orginalpoint.X - width_incrasesBy * mouse_widthPercent / 100,

              Orginalpoint.Y - height_incresesBy * mouse_heightPercent / 100

              );
       
        return new RectangleF(newPoint, newSize);

    }

    

}
```